# How is possible that Ubuntu 12.04 32bit can see all of 6gb ram

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit, ram

I have Ubuntu 12.04 32bit and system is displaying all of my ram 5.7 GiB, how is this possible?

Comment: You have a integrated video card ?

Comment: `uname -a` will show `3.2.0-24-generic-pae` The pae part allows you to use more ram ;)

Comment: @warl0ck yup i have intel hd3000 and gf325

Comment: @Rinzwind right , cool :)

Answer (score 3):

Because Ubuntu 12.04 is using the PAE kernel by default.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

Answer (score 1):

Physical address extension - aka PAE - lets the CPU "address" (Which means see and use) all the available memory.

How? PAE kernels (yours, for example) use a nice trick wich is transparent to applications, remapping physical memory. It's a sort of workaround, you can find more info here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension.
Anyways, you'd better switch to 64bit!

Comment: I did try 64bit version but there was lots of problems, and system was unusable so i switched back to 32bit

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126061/ubuntu-12-04-64-update-error